# Python typing - TypeVar for something that inherits from multiple base classes

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

Python's [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) allows setting a `bound` for a type, like so

```py
from typing import TypeVar


class A:
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)


def foo(_: T) -> None:
    pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C:
    pass


foo(B())  # OK
foo(C())  # error: Value of type variable "T" of "foo" cannot be "C"
```

My question is how can I express "any type T where T inherits from X *and* Y"?

This was my first naive attempt:

```py
from typing import TypeVar


class X:
    pass


class Y:
    pass


class XY(X, Y):
    pass


T = TypeVar("T", bound=XY)


def foo(_: T) -> None:
    pass


class MyClass(X, Y):
    pass


foo(MyClass())  # error: Value of type variable "T" of "foo" cannot be "MyClass"
```

This doesn't work, because `MyClass` isn't a subclass of `XY`, and mypy correctly rejects the code.

In this minimal example I could do `class MyClass(XY)`, but this isn't a good solution for the actual code I'm working with. Consider what happens if there are classes `X1`, `X2`, ..., `Xn`, and I have functions that expect types that inherit from some subset of these. Making a class for each combination would be infeasible, as `MyClass` would need to inherit from each "combo-class".

Essentially I'm looking for something equivalent to this fictional code:

```py
T = TypeVar("T", bound=(X, Y))  # Not allowed

def foo(x: T):
    assert isinstance(x, X)
    assert isinstance(x, Y)
```

Any thought's on how this could be done, or achieve something to this effect?

Comment: This is not supported in python type system now, here's the relevant [python/typing issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only support the current Python typing system has for type hinting multiple inheritance is through a `Protocol`, where all the bases also have be `Protocol`s, as documented in [PEP-544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#unions-and-intersections-of-protocols):

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

class X(Protocol):
    pass

class Y(Protocol):
    pass

class XY(X, Y, Protocol):
    pass

T = TypeVar("T", bound=XY)

def foo(_: T) -> None:
    pass

class MyClass(X, Y):
    pass

foo(MyClass())
```

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=f392ad6b46ff9b87c1f3e574bc7626c6

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly the `all bases also have to be Protocol` requirement breaks it for me, as I have `pydantic.BaseModel`s in there too. But perhaps I can refactor my way out of it, maybe using protocols.